# Magento - checkout onpage registration get password

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an extension to creating md5 password and sync the email and md5 password with our 3rd party db to use in other tool. on the Resignation page works perfect but we have problem on the checkout Resignation, it is not getting the password and has no possibility to sync and save that in the db. here is the code:

in `app/code/local/SyncUsers/config.xml`

in the events global:

```
 <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <md5password>
                    <class>membership/observer</class>
                    <method>storeMD5Password</method>
                </md5password>
            </observers>
</customer_save_before>
```

in `app/code/local/SyncUsers/membership/Observer.php`

```
public $_singletonFlag = false;

public function storeMD5Password($observer)
{
    // Prevent the save_handler to call itself and end-up with infinite loops.
    if($this->singletonFlag) {
        return;
    }
    $this->singletonFlag = true;

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    if ($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {

        if ($new_password = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('password', false) && strlen($new_password) > 0) {
            $customer->setData('md5_password', md5($new_password));
            $customer->save(); 
        }
    }
}
```

in the onpage checkout it is not passing the password and not convert them to md5!

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing a simple MD5 hash of the password against the customer? Magento's password system is bad enough, please don't make it worse.

Comment: unfortunately yes, and canot do anything with that as it is the 3rd party tool and use simple md5 hash :(